# Procedure or function 'spUpdateUserProfile' expects parameter '@QuestionID', which was not supplied when i run this

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am having issues with either my Visual Studio OR SQL Server today.

First I tried executing a stored procedure using C# and an error is returned saying I was missing a parameter which I had defined, so I added

```
System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
```

and now the error has changed to

> Could not find stored procedure EXEC dbo.spUpdateUserProfile @userID,@UserName,@FirstName,@MiddleName,@LastName,@email,@QuestionID

Comment: the error is pretty self explanatory

Comment: The store procedure is there man, ive double checked a million times, been tying to solve this problem all day and am pretty experienced with stored procedures and c# but this one seems to be having some problems

Comment: May be you are accessing wrong database : add some code

Comment: To execute a stored procedure you set the CommandText to the **name** of the stored procedure, i.e. `spUpdateUserProfile`

Comment: need more code, error is exactly what it says.